# How to write the opposite of Promise.race

Tags: javascript

I have some 3 asynchronous functions.

I have to create function which get that 3 functions and some callback in arguments and call that callback when last asynchronous function has ended, then, send value the of that function's callback argument to callback.

That 3 functions have 1 callback arguments:

```
const async1 = (cb) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        cb(1);
    }, 4000);
};
const async2 = (cb) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        cb(13);
    }, 6000);
};
const async3 = (cb) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        cb(5);
    }, 3000);
};
const someCallback = (val) => console.log(val);
 yourXFunction(async1, async2, async3, someCallback);
 // for this case, should print 13
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what is the problem with it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Also: `yourXFunction` suggests this is homework. It's **particularly** important to show your effort when asking for help with homework.

Comment: Side note: What you have in your question are functions that complete asynchronously and would often have been called "async functions" or "asynchronous functions" just a few years ago. Since ES2015 defined `async` functions (functions that use the `async` keyword), the phrase "async function" has a more specific meaning that doesn't match the above. Just in case you find information about them when searching and it gets confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily implement a such function:

```js
function yourXFunction(...args){
  const cb=args.pop()
  const cbCreator=i=>value=>{
    if(done.add(i).size===args.length){
      cb(value)
    }
  }
  const done=new Set
  args.map((fn,i)=>{
    fn(cbCreator(i))
  })
}
```

But note that...

- Avoid use of callbacks in favor of Promises (or, even better, `async`/`await`)
- Due to single-threadedness of JS, racing 'asynchronous' things may produce unexpected results

Here is a promisified version of your code:

```js
const wait = t => new Promise(rs => setTimeout(rs, t))
const async1 = () => wait(4000).then(()=>1)
const async2 = () => wait(6000).then(()=>13)
const async3 = () => wait(3000).then(()=>5)

function promisifiedYourXFunction(...args){
  return new Promise(resolve=>{
    const cbCreator=i=>value=>{
      if(done.add(i).size===args.length){
        resolve(value)
      }
    }
    const done=new Set
    args.map((fn,i)=>{
      fn().then(cbCreator(i))
    })
  })
}

promisifiedYourXFunction(async1, async2, async3)
.then(console.log)
```